# Triggering a server to shutdown in receiving a signal via serial port (RS232)

Tags: linux, shutdown, serial-port

I'm a fresh graduate (Electronics & Commn) and want to start my career in linux administration. I'm using a Ubunutu 14.04 server machine for R&D (with ups). Now my scenario is whenever main power supply goes off and ups gives backup, a message or signal from ups has to be sent to the server machine and make it to shutdown. How to accomplish this task. Can anyone help me with this. Pls don't post that already some tools/software's are available like that. I need a clear small brief about how these stuffs work's inside a linux-carton

Comment: Could you provide which UPS model you're using?

Answer (score 2):

> Pls don't post that already some tools/software's are available like that. I need a clear small brief about how these stuffs work's inside a linux-carton

I am afraid this is exactly the case and possibly the best approach. The UPS vendor often provides tools to do stuff like that. I posses a APC UPS and the software provided by the vendor works flawlessly. Since you did not mention the make of your UPS I'll try to provide you with more generic information.

**How this works?**

The software runs as a daemon which listens on what ever port you specify in the configfile. You also need to specify your model, so the daemon is aware of its capabilities and the protocol which is used. This information is most likely stored in files provided by the vendor. There are usually a variety of options ranging from RS232, over USB to Ethernet or TCP/IP. The configfiles often provide the possibility to define script files that are to be executed if a specific event occurs. You can place your shutdown commands and any other command or script there.

Your best shot might be `apcupsd` or `NUT`, for both of these you can find official Ubuntu documentation as well as many different HowTo's from other sources. I can tell you from personal experience that the apcupsd manpages and comments in the configfiles are very helpful.

**What are the benefits?**

- Some of these daemons can run in a server/client relationship. You
  set up one machine to monitor the UPS and serve the information to
  other machines that are connected to the same UPS, or like in my case
  run on the same host.
- Some these tools offer you analysis and configuration functionality
  for the connected UPS.
- You can react to many different events like: Battery charged left,
  estimated battery time left, elapsed time since power loss, or a
  combination of the above which ever first occurs.

**How to do this on your own?**

1. you need to get your hands on the employed protocol. If you are
   lucky the vendor has documented it publicly. If not: Since you want
   to use RS232 you'll need some kind of sniffer and then reverse
   engineer the protocol.
2. Write a daemon that listens on the RS232 port to catch the
   information sent by the UPS and execute the commands you want.
3. Make it generic and publish it under GPL. :)
4. Maintain your code and keep track of new models on the market.

I would really recommend you to go with the first option.